# Adding to a value when 'x' detected in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

test1:

```
id: 1
name: apple
count: 0

id: 2
name: pear
count: 0
```

test2:

```
id: 1
liked: yes
itemid: 1

id: 2
liked: yes
itemid: 1

id: 3
liked: yes
itemid: 2
```

Every time `test2.itemid` matches `test1.id` I want to add 1 to `test1.count`. In the instance above, apple would have a count of 2.

I have tried the query below,

```
UPDATE test1
LEFT JOIN
        test2
ON      test2.`itemid` = test1.`id`
SET     test1.`count` = test1.`count` + 1
WHERE   test2.`liked` = 'yes';
```

and this happens:

test1:

```
id: 1
name: apple
count: 1

id: 2
name: pear
count: 1
```

As you can see it hasn't worked properly. I am guessing it just ran once for each row in test1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE test1 t1
   SET `count` = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM test2 t2
                   WHERE t1.id = t2.itemid 
                     AND liked = 'yes');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd sum the `test2` values, then add. Also note that if you only care about `test1` rows with "likes" in `test2`, that's an inner join:

```
UPDATE test1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT itemid, COUNT(*) AS valueToAdd
  FROM test2
  WHERE liked = 'yes'
  GROUP BY itemid) test2Counts
ON test1.id = test2Counts.itemid
SET test1.`count` = test1.`count` + test2Counts.valueToAdd;
```

Comment: This works great, personally I would prefer to use Olli's answer due to simplicity. Thanks for the inner join tip also, didn't know that :P

Comment: No problem - I also like Olli's answer for its simplicity. If you have a very large data set then consider mine; chances are it'll be a bit faster (just one scan through `test2` instead of once for each row in `test1`), but if the data set is relatively small there's no need to trade speed for readability.